# How to share the data to the child component in laravel from the Controller and also return the views of the child components

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Please help me, i want to share my data from the database to the child blade component and also return the views of the component.

I'm using layouts with @yield in my parent layout.

```
<body>
    @include('Layout.topbar') // this the component that i want to share with the data from the database

    @include('Layout.navbar')

    @yield('content') // this the views that i want to return

    @include('Layout.footer')
</body>
```

This is my contoller look like:

```
$carouselImages = CarouselImage::active()->get();
$newsActivities = NewsActivities::active()->get();

$contact = Contact::all(); // this the data that i want to share to the topbar.blade.php

view()->share('contacts', $contact); // this work, but after navigate to the other page, it's show an errors about the $contacts undefined.

return view('Home.isi', [
    'carouselImages' => $carouselImages,
    'newsActivities' => $newsActivities
]);
```

i'd tried to find that simple trick, but i can't find the right one.

Please help ~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better not make database or cache queries in a boot method of a service provider. This code will be executed for every request, even for post requests.

As far as I understand:

- You have a topbar, navbar and a footer. In between you yield the content of your page
- The view `Home.isi` is returned in a controller (will be injected with the yield) where you fetch the contacts to share.
- You want however, that the Topbar has always access to the contacts.

Did I understand correctly? If this is the case I think view composers are the best fit for you: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/views#view-composers

You can register those for different views, like for `Layout.topbar`. And everytime the topbar is rendered you can add the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider putting it in boot method of a provider, such as AppServiceProvider:

```
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $contact = Contact::all(); // this the data that i want to share to the topbar.blade.php
    view()->share('contacts', $contact); // this work, but after navigate to the other page, it's show an errors about the $contacts undefined.
}
```

For the better performance, you can put contacts in cache and then retrieve it from cache.